# Error around my while loop, after first execution no longer asks for input

Tags: c++

```
// Program to loop results, and average them

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const int Limit = 5;
    double Grades, ModuleNumber;


    for(double ModuleNumber = 0; ModuleNumber < Limit ; ++ModuleNumber)
    {
        std::cout << "Module Number:" << ModuleNumber + 1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Input your grades:" << std::endl;

        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (std::cin >> Grades)
        {
            ++count;
            sum += Grades;
        }

        double AverageGrade = sum / count;

        std::cout << "The average Grade for Module: "<< ModuleNumber + 1 << " is "<< AverageGrade << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

After my first execution of the code it instantly iterated through the next 4 loops, and shows the result of the average as:

> -nan(ind)

I'm new to the programming scene and was wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Make `sum` and `count` outside `for loop` because they are reset each iteration to 0.

Comment: Pretty sure he's doing that for individual modules with multiple grades not all the modules.

Comment: When `while (std::cin >> Grades)` will stop? It'll stop only if cin failed.

Comment: You define  `ModuleNumber` here `double Grades, ModuleNumber;` and here `for (double ModuleNumber = 0; ModuleNumber < Limit; ++ModuleNumber)`. Only the inner most `ModuleNumber` is live at any given time but both exist and are different. This doesn't hurt in this program, but it could bite you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating-point value of NaN (regardless of capitalization) usually comes from dividing zero by zero. (NaN stands for Not a Number). If `std::cin >> Grades` failed the first time through the loop, the loop would end immediately, and `sum` and `count` would both be zero, and the value of `AverageGrade` would be NaN. So chances are you didn’t enter a valid floating-point value when prompted.

Comment: How could I work it to exit after entering an invalid type, and still continue the loop?

Comment: @Jack — read the input into a string and try to convert it. If the conversion fails you’re still in control.